# How to obtain data from a database and put it inside fxml?

Tags: java, sql, javafx, fxml

I'm making some kind of information application about a city which I need to use a database for, I got my database set up and ready and most of the code needed as well; the only part is to extract the data I need from my SQL server into a `BarChart` in fxml. Can anyone give me a example or something?

My fxml:

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controllers.ControllerZW">
    <BarChart fx:id="graph" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
        <xAxis>
            <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
            <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
        </yAxis>
    </BarChart>
</Pane>
```

My controller atm:

```
package Controllers;

public class ControllerZW implements Interface.Ibacktomenu {

    @Override
    public void backtomenu() {
        try {
            Main.mainStage.setScene(
                    new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../scenes/MainMenu.fxml")))
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Probably couldnt find resource file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to render the data form database to XML format?

I think some template engine maybe help you, such as Freemarker.

You could use Freemarker as view of Spring MVC, please refer to http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-freemarker-ftl-example/

Comment: Creating a fxml file for the data is more complicated than necessary. All that has to be done is converting the data from the database to the data for the `BarChart` (which does not take xml format btw...) and assigning it to the chart...

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) to get the data from the database and any method described in *[Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)* to get the data to the controller, e.g.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Task<Pane> dataLoader = new Task<Pane>() {

        @Override
        protected Pane call() throws Exception {
            // create data
            XYChart.Series<String, Double> rain = new XYChart.Series<>();
            rain.setName("rain");

            Month[] months = Month.values();

            for (Month month : months) {
                // simulates slow database connection; just adding some random values here
                Thread.sleep(200);
                rain.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(month.toString(), Math.random() * 100));
            }
            // load chart (replace BarChartLoad.class.getResource("chart.fxml") with your own URL)
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(BarChartLoad.class.getResource("chart.fxml"));
            Pane pane = loader.load();
            // pass data to controller
            loader.<ControllerZW>getController().setData(FXCollections.observableArrayList(rain));
            return pane;
        }

    };

    // placeholder
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 600);

    // set new scene root on successfull completion of the task
    dataLoader.setOnSucceeded(evt -> scene.setRoot(dataLoader.getValue()));

    // TODO: handle task failure

    new Thread(dataLoader).start();

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

```
public class ControllerZW implements Interface.Ibacktomenu {

    @FXML
    private BarChart<String, Double> graph;

    public void setData(ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Double>> data) {
        graph.setData(data);
    }
    ...
```